How to understand independent and identically distributed sample?
I am reading A Probability Path and solving an exercise:

Suppose the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal B, P)$ is $([0, 1], \mathcal B, \lambda)$ where $\mathcal B$ is the class of Borel sets of $\Omega = [0, 1]$ and $\lambda$ is uniform that is $\lambda([0, \omega]) = \omega$ for any $\omega \in [0, 1]$.
Define a random variable $X(\omega) = \omega$.
Can we find a r.v. which is not almost surely non constant such that it is independent with $X$?

The sulotion is No since the generated sigma algebra of $X$ is $\sigma(X) = \mathcal B$, otherwise suppose that there ia a r.v. $Y$ independent of $X$, then for any event $A$ in $\sigma(Y)$ which is not trivial, taking $A \in \sigma(X)$, $P(A \cap A) \neq P(A) P(A)$.
By the exercise, we can conclude that for any $X$ such that $\sigma(X) = \mathcal B$, then there can not exist a non constant r.v. independent of $X$.
My question is how can we generate i.i.d. samples from uniform distribution since there is not r.v. independent of $X$ defined in the exercise?
Or say what does the terminology i.i.d. sample mean? Can anyone describe in a mathematical manner?

The particular choice of $X$ does not allow for another non-trivial  independent RV, but the probability space is rich enough to allow an  infinite sequence of IID $U[0,1]$ without external construction of a  product space. Here is one way of doing it. I'm skipping some details.
Every irrational $\omega$ is uniquely represented by its binary expansion: a unique sequence $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots)$ taking values in $\{0,1\}$ such that: $\omega =\sum_{i=1}^\infty \omega_i 2^{-i}$. The irrational $\omega$'s are a set of measure $1$. Note that for each $i$, the mapping  $\omega \to \omega_i$ (which we can arbitrarily define as $0$ for rational numbers) is a random variable as it is an indicator of a Borel set (and as such a Borel  function of $X$). Call this RV $X_i$. Then $X=\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i 2^{-i}$ a.s.  This will be useful in item 3 below.
Now:

The sequence $(X_i:i\in{\mathbb N})$ is IID Bernoulli with probability of success $\frac 12$.
This sequence has infinitely many disjoint subsequences (e.g. all positive powers of $2$,  $3$, ... all positive powers the prime $p$, ...).
For each subsequence $(X_{i_k}:k\in{\mathbb N})$, the distribution of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty X_{i_k} 2^{-k}$ is Uniform on $[0,1]$.
Therefore the measure space contains in infinite sequence of IID Uniform $[0,1]$ RVs.

This is one of the reasons why one Uniform RV on $[0,1]$ is basically all we need for a lot of probability theory...

Does the $X$ defined in the second paragraph satisfy that $X(\omega) = \omega$ such that $\sigma(X) = \mathcal B([0, 1]$?

Yes. This is the same X as in question.

I can see that RVs $\sum_{k=1} X_{i_k} 2^{-k}$ are independent and uniformly distributed. But is there a contradiction between ur argument and the exercise?

No. Everything independent of $X$ is trivial.  There are IID uniform, all of which are functions of $X$, but none is independent of $X$...
